# Problemas para instalar rbenv

Tags: windows, ruby

seguí estos pasos https://gorails.com/setup/windows/10

```
cd                                                                                     git clone https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv                          
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc                       
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc                                     
exec $SHELL
git clone https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build  
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc    
exec $SHELL
rbenv install 3.0.1
```

me muestra este mensaje

```
 /tmp/ruby-build.20210522125155.2456.WHYkIT/ruby-2.3.3
```

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir el log completo de lo que te muestra? Lo que compartes no dice mucho (nada en realidad) de lo que puede estar sucediendo. Tampoco entiendo porque te mostraría algo relacionado con ruby-2.3.3 cuando estás instalando 3.0.1. ¿qué te muestra `rbenv versions`?

Comment: mp/ruby-build.20210522135630.2366.ANmvTb ~
/tmp/ruby-build.20210522135630.2366.ANmvTb/ruby-2.5.1 /tmp/ruby-build.20210522135630.2366.ANmvTb ~
checking for ruby... false
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/tmp/ruby-build.20210522135630.2366.ANmvTb/ruby-2.5.1':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details

Comment: Por favor, edita tu pregunta y agrega ahí la información, no como un comentario que queda ilegible sin los saltos de línea. Por lo que sale, no tienes un compilador C instalado. ¿Seguiste la indicación previa de la guía de correr `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install git-core curl zlib1g-dev build-essential libssl-dev libreadline-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev software-properties-common libffi-dev`? eso debería instalar las dependencias que requieres. Si lo hiciste, fíjate si te tiró algún error en esa parte y agrégalo a la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

A 4 meses de la publicación. Es mi intención ayudarte. Cabe mencionar que soy nuevo en el mundo de programación con RoR, sin embargo me gusta tomarme un tiempo para aprender de los errores comunes. Me ayuda aprender un poco más.

Sinceras disculpas si alguien es muy ultra-ortodoxo con las políticas *Stack OverFlow*

---

VEO QUE ESTA GUIA ES PARA WSL (WINDOWS SUB-SYSTEM LINUX)

Al leer tu pregunta inicial pareciera un problema con RBENV, sin embargo en tu siguiente mensaje, se menciona en el log:

```
checking for ruby... false checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
```

Revise la guia y todo parece en orden, está actualizada se puede decir, sin embargo hay una instrucción muy común cuando se trabaja con entornos linux que no vi en la guia; esta línea suele usarse regularmente cuando se hacen despliegues Ruby on Rails en Heroku que usa linux y postgreSQL.

```
bundle lock --add-platform x86_64-linux --add-platform ruby
```